# Does a manifold quotient group action need to be Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

If the group $G$ acts continuously on a manifold $M$, does $M/G$ need to be Hausdorff? I don't think it does, but i can't think of any counterexamples.

Comment: Take $M = \Bbb{R}$ and $G = \Bbb{Q}$ acting on $M$ by $q: x \mapsto x + q$.

Comment: If $G$ is compact (or acts properly), yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$"Natural" examples include the multiplicative group of real numbers, $(\Reals^{\times}, \cdot)$, acting on:

- The real line $M = \Reals$ by $g_{t}(x) = tx$. (The quotient is a two-point space; one point is closed, the other is open and dense.)
- The punctured plane $M = \Reals^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ by $g_{t}(x, y) = (tx, \frac{1}{t}y)$. (The quotient is the [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins).)